# Inheritance in Javascript. Do I inherit the methode with the object? How can I reach the result?

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, methods

I try to exercise inherity in Javascript. eCar inherited from car an car inheritedd from Vehicle. But it seems i can't use the method "getInfo()"  with a Car- or eCar-Object.
If I execute this in my browser the result is:

```
Manufacture: Siemens

undefined
undefined
```

Whats I'm searching for is:

```
Manufacture: Siemens
Manufacture: VW
Manufacture: Tesla
```

.

```
function Vehicle(herst){

    this.manuf = herst;
}

Vehicle.prototype.getInfo = function(){
    return 'Manufacture: '+ this.manuf+'<br>';
}


Car.prototype = Vehicle;
Car.prototype.construtor = Vehicle;
Car.prototype.getInfo = Vehicle;


function Car(){ }

eCar.prototype = Car;
eCar.prototype.construtor = Car;
eCar.prototype.getInfo = Car;

function eCar(){ }


Train = new Vehicle('Siemens');
document.write(Train.getInfo()+"<br>");


Golf = new Car('VW');
document.write(Golf.getInfo()+"<br>");


Tesla = new eCar('Tesla');
document.write(Tesla.getInfo()+"<br>");
```

Comment: I recommend to have a look at [Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript). It provides an example about how to set up inheritance.

Comment: I think it's `Car.prototype = new Vehicle();` and `eCar.prototype = new Car();` etc. isn't it?

Comment: @Andy better not, you're creating a Vehicle instance to set prototype of Car. Vehicle has instance specific members that are now on the shared prototype of Car and that can have unexpected results. You can mediate that by having `Vehicle.call(this,args)` in the Car constructor but you still can run into trouble when creating an instance of Vehicle is inconvenient at the time of defining the objects. Better to use Object.create and polyfil it for older browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, just a couple things needed to be different.

```
// Vehicle
function Vehicle(herst){
    this.manuf = herst;
}
Vehicle.prototype.getInfo = function () {
    return 'Manufacture: '+ this.manuf+'<br>'; // you really want to return HTML?
};
Vehicle.prototype.construtor = Vehicle;

// Car
function Car(){
    Vehicle.apply(this, arguments); // extends Vehicle
}
Car.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle.prototype); // inherits Vehicle's prototype
Car.prototype.construtor = Car;

// eCar
function eCar(){ // constructors usually start with a capital
    Car.apply(this, arguments); // extends Car
}
eCar.prototype = Object.create(Car.prototype);
eCar.prototype.construtor = eCar;

// use it

var Train = new Vehicle('Siemens'), // variables usually start lower case
    Golf = new Car('VW'),
    Tesla = new eCar('Tesla');
```

I chose [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) to set up the inheritance, some people prefer using the format of `Bar.prototype = new Foo()` but I feel that this invokes the constructor `Foo` at the wrong time.

---

What does this look like?

```
var foo = new eCar('Foo');
foo instanceof eCar;    // foo has eCar's prototype
                        // eCar was used to construct foo
foo instanceof Car;     // foo inherited Car's prototype via eCar's prototype
                        // at the beginning of eCar, Car was applied to foo
foo instanceof Vehicle; // foo inherited Vehicle's prototype via Car's prototype
                        // at the beginning of Car, Vehicle was applied to foo
/*
    So `foo` has own properties as assigned by Vehicle, then Car, then eCar,
    and it has the prototype from eCar which shadows the prototype from Car
    which again shadows the prototype from Vehicle
*/
```